# How to find the correct brackets sequence?

Tags: c, algorithm, c++17, sequence

I've to figure it out that the bracket sequence is correct. Here is my problem.
[Neat bracket](https://toph.co/p/neat-brackets)

& Here is my solution code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100];
    int c=0,count1=0,count2=0,count3=0;
    scanf("%[^\n]",s);
    while(s[c] !='\0')
        {
        if(s[c] == '(')
        {
            ++count1;
        }
        if(s[c] == ')')
        {
            ++count2;
        }
        if(s[c] == '"')
        {
            ++count3;
        }
        ++c;
    }
    if(count1==count2 && count3%2 ==0)
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it returns incorrect answer for a test case. & I also know that the algorithm is not proper 'cause it fails to give the correct answer for this test case

> )))""(((

So how can I improve my algorithm???

Comment: Hints: Have you heard of the Data structure 'stacks'? It has operations called push and pop.

Comment: No I don't know about data structure

Comment: A stack is not necessary to solve this. Hint: For the string `(()))(` which has an equal count, what are `count1` and `count2` at each step? Something happens for the first time at the initial substring `(()))` which hints at a problem....

Comment: partial suggestion: a single counter for parentheses; increment it when "`(`"; decrement  it and check isn't less than zero for ")"; check it's zero at the end. No idea how can mix with `"`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to learn about stacks. You'll be fine if you know arrays or vectors. This question is best solved with it ( There might be other better ways but this was my approach to solve it)

Comment: Are you using C or C++? They are different languages, and the "right" solution will depend on which you choose. Please update your question's tags to remove the one you're not using.

Comment: Why are you trying to match the `"` character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've done. Here is my solve. Thanks to  " max66 ".
So in this problem , you've to identify one most important thing that ")" isn't used without its closing tags. That's I've done.
Here is my solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c=0,count1=0,count2=0;
    char s[1000];
    scanf("%[^\n]",s);
    while(s[c] != '\0')
    {
        if(s[c] == '"')
        {
            ++count2;
        }
        if(s[c] == ')')
        {
            --count1;
        }
        if (count1 != -1)
        {
            if(s[c]== '(')
            {
               ++count1;
            }
        }

        ++c;
    }
    ///printf("%d\n",count1);
    ///printf("%d\n",count2);
    if(count1 == 0 && count2%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Every thing is OK!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Something is fishy!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Comment: ok, I'll try to do (my English is very poor. I hope people will understand).

Answer (score 1):

Do it with [std::stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/). Idea is to

1. If stack is empty, push `s[i]` to stack.
2. Compare current character aka `s[i]` with `stack.top()` and pop stack if does match.
3. Push  current character aka `s[i]` onto stack when no match is found.

Assume input is : "()(())". Now,

A. i = 0. Initially stack is empty. Push "(" on stack. Stack - "(".

B. i = 1. Stack is not empty. Compare ")" aka s[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) with stack's top - "(". It does match. Now, pop stack. Stack - "".

C. i = 2. Now stack is empty. Push "(" on stack. Stack - "(".

D. i = 3. Stack is not empty. Compare "(" aka s[3] with stack's top - ")". It does not match. Now, push "(" to stack. Stack - "(("

E. i = 4. Stack is not empty. Compare ")" aka s[4] with stack's top - "(". It does match. Now, pop stack.  Stack - "("

F. i = 5. Stack is not empty. Compare ")" aka s[5] with stack's top - "(". It does match. Now, pop stack. Stack - ""

Now, Stack is empty, We can say string is neat - as mentioned in question. Had we left with any unmatched parenthesis in stack, that'd mean string is not neat.

```
     //Assuming s is the char array containing parenthesis sequence.
     int i = 0;
     std::stack<char> st;
     while(s[i] != '\0') //Better choice would be to use std::string
     {
        if(st.empty() )
        {
             st.push( s[i++] ); 
             continue;
        } 
        if( st.top() == '(' && s[i] == ')' )
            { st.pop(); i++ }
        else
            st.push(s[i++]);   

      }
       if(st.empty() )  
          printf("Yes");
       else 
          printf("No");
```